# dot tk domain can not redriect to sub files/folders

Tags: redirect, web-hosting

I just registered a dot tk that redirect to my wordpress site. The problem is that i can't redirect it to sub files or folders. For example a.tk/wp-admin/ can't go to log in page. What should I config or dot tk domain can't do that?

Comment: How are you redirecting it (or trying to)?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Actually, I want to verify my .tk site with google. So i need to upload the html file to the root dir of my site.  But I can't view the mysite.tk/google.html.